# How to convert yyyymmddhhmm to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.uuu in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

How to convert

```
yyyymmddhhmm
```

to

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.uuu
```

in SQL Server 2008 ?

Comment: Is your date a `varchar`, `text` or in a `datetime` column? More detail would be good.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D+convert+date+format

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to retrieve to insert into database?

anyway you can change and convert by CONVERT() Function

try this code

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, Update_Date , 126) FROM Tbl_TEST
```

for reference

http://www.petefreitag.com/item/687.cfm

http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/